# Map<String, Entity> with composite key in Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dictionary, jpa-2.0

I've got the following two tables:

```
TABLE A:
  INT      id
  VARCHAR  x
PRIMARY KEY (id)

TABLE B:
  INT      a_id
  VARCHAR  locale
  VARCHAR  z
PRIMARY KEY (a_id, locale)
```

It's basically a simple OneToMany relation. Table `B` contains the the id (`a_id`) of the referenced row in Table `A` plus a `locale`. This means: Every entry in `A` can have `0..*` entries in Table `B`, each one with a distinct `locale` value.

I have the following two classes, which should represent those tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
class A {
  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  int id;

  @Column(name="x")
  String x;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="a") // ???
  @MapKey... // ???
  Map<String, B> bMap;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
class B {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="a_id")
  A a;

  @Column(name="locale")
  String locale;

  @Column(name="z")
  String z;
}
```

Now two things are missing:

1. The Annotations for `Map<String, B> bMap`. I just don't know if I should use a `@MapKey` or `@MapKeyColumn` and how to map to that composite key. And if I should/have to use `@OneToMany`?
2. The `B` class of course needs a composite key. Should I use an `@EmbeddedId` or `@IdClass`?

Could you provide some example code for this scenario?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Working solution at the bottom

---

I think, I've now managed to put things together. At least the generated SQL Tables look right, though I still have to figure out how to get Cascaded Saving done...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
public class A {
   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   long id;

   @Column(name="x")
   String x;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="id.a", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
   @MapKey(name="id.locale")
   Map<String, B> bMap = new HashMap<String, B>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
public class B {
   @EmbeddedId
   BPK id;

   @Column(name="z")
   String z;
}

@Embeddable
public class BPK implements Serializable {
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="a_id")
   A a;

   @Column(name="locale")
   String locale;

   // equals + hashcode
}
```

When calling `aRepository.findById(...)` Hibernates gives:

```
Hibernate: select * from A a where a.id=?
```

which is correct.

But if I call `aEntity.getBMap()` it always fetches the whole map, even if I just want to use `aEntity.getBMap().put("EN", someBObject)` and don't want to read any data from it. But that's okay for now.

Now I've just to figure out how to get Cascaded Saving to work. When doing `aEntity.getBMap().put("EN", someBObject); aRepository.save(eEntity);` I get

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class B
```

I think I'm just missing some setters for the `@EmbeddedId` or it's fields.

---

## FINALLY SOLVED:

Cascaded saving somehow didn't work with `@EmbeddedId` composite key. So I thought about it and figured out, that I could instead use an `@ElementCollection`! `:)`.

So here's what I finally did:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
public class A {
   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   long id;

   @Column(name="x")
   String x;

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="B", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="a_id"))
   @MapKeyColumn(name="locale")
   Map<String, B> bMap = new HashMap<String, B>();
}

@Embeddable
public class B {
   @Column(name="z")
   String z;
}
```

Hibernate outputs:

`A a = aRepository.findById(...)`

- Hibernate: select * from A where id=?

`a.getBMap().put("EN", someBObject)`

- Hibernate: select * from B where a_id=?

`aRepository.save(a)`

- Hibernate: insert into B (a_id, locale, z) values (?, ?, ?)